# Why does this program loop right away and not when it should be?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
public class assignment2 {
    public static int t1;
    public static int t2;
    public static int x;
    public static int y1;
    public static int m1;
    public static int d1;
    public static int y2;
    public static int m2;
    public static int d2;
    public static void date1() {
        int x = 0;  // Integer for looping.
        do          // Process to follow if length == 5.
        {           // Notify program what to do while under loop limit.
            Scanner scanner  = new Scanner (System.in);
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter the first date ");
                System.out.println ("Please enter the year: ");
                y1=scanner.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Please enter the month: ");
                m1=scanner.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Please enter the day: ");
                d1=scanner.nextInt();}
            catch ( InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) // Error if  wrong character is inputted.
            {
                scanner.nextLine() ;
                System.err.printf( "You must enter intergers. Please try again.\n" ); // Prompt user to enter integers.
            } // Set loop to three attempts.
        }
        while (x < 3) ;

        int j = 693502;
        if (t1 > j) {
            if (m1==1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 8 + 10 + 12) {
                t1 = ((365*y1)+d1+31);
            }
            else
                if (m1==2) {
                    t1 = ((365*y1)+d1+28);
                }
                else
                    if (m1==4 + 6 + 9 + 11); {
                        t1 = ((365*y1)+d1+30);
                    }
            x = x + 1; // Set loop to three attempts
            while (x < 3) ;
        }
        else {
            System.err.printf ("Error. Please enter a date after Jan 1st 1900.\n") ;
        }
    }

    public static void date2() {
        int x = 0; // Integer for looping
        do         // Process to follow if length == 5
        {
            Scanner scanner  = new Scanner (System.in);
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter the first date ");
                System.out.println ("Please enter the year: ");
                y2=scanner.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Please enter the month: ");
                m2=scanner.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Please enter the day: ");
                d2=scanner.nextInt();}
            catch ( InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) // Error if wrong character is inputted.
            {
                scanner.nextLine() ;
                System.err.printf( "You must enter intergers. Please try again. " ); // Prompt user to enter integers.
            }
            x = x + 1; // Set loop to three attempts
        }
        while (x < 3) ;
        int j = 693502;
        if (t1 > j) {
            if (m1==1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 8 + 10 + 12) {
                t1 = ((365*y1)+d1+31);
            }
            else
                if (m1==2) {
                    t1 = ((365*y1)+d1+28);
                }
                else
                    if (m1==4 + 6 + 9 + 11); {
                        t1 = ((365*y1)+d1+30);
                    }
            x = x + 1; // Set loop to three attempts.
            while (x < 3) ;
        }
        else {
            System.err.printf ("Error. Please enter a date after Jan 1st 1900. ");
        }
    }

    public static void finaldate1() {
        x = Math.abs(t1-t2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        date1();
        date2();
        finaldate1();
        System.out.println("The difference between the two dates is: " + x + " days.");
    }
}
```

What is the reason my loops do not respond properly? How could I set a proper error catch and loop for when non integers are being inputted or if the total days of date inputted are smaller than 693502 (1990 January 1st).

Comment: If this is homework you should label it as homework. And I really hope this is not what you turn in because I can't read at all what the code is doing.

Comment: You've tagged this Eclipse. Ctrl+Shift+F will automatically format this with sensible indentation. This will help you see the structure of the program, which might help you debug it.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the semi-colon at the end of the while-lines and sorround the area you want to include in the loop in brackets, i.e. { and }

Answer (score 0):

Your loop conditions are wrong. For example, in the `date1` input loop, you have `while (x < 3);` But `x` is never modified inside that loop.

Answer (score 0):

First, look at the errors and get it to compile.

1. Half of the while loops are standalone, not doing anything.
2. All of the while loops are referencing an x which is not being set,
3. and furthermore you are overriding the class level x variable with a local variable, which is not currently an error, but is likely to lead to one.

General debugging advice, break the problem into small pieces, and confirm the small pieces work.  Save the working (ideally version control) before starting the next piece so you can always go back to working code.